# Centering screen output to screen width

Tags: javascript

Centering screen output to screen width

I'm using 3GL logic here to initialize a global variable (ScreenX) to represent the screen's starting X position from where a 1024px wide page will be displayed.

Is this the correct approach to center everything on the screen or does the Web scripting world offer something else for this task?

Thanks for your input. Code follows…

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><body>

 <script>

 if (screen.width>1024)
  {
  ScreenX=(screen.width-1024)/2;
  }
 else
   {
  ScreenX=0;
   }

 </script>

 </body></html>
```

Comment: Is `margin:auto` not doing the trick for you?

Comment: Thanks, I have to study that... I hope it's not more laborious than saying ScreenX+120 as an example.

Comment: It's a simple CSS declaration. It will center something horizontally inside of its parent container. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/cMcXc/

Comment: Right, so there is no global declaration to get everything centered I presume...

Comment: You could do `*{margin: auto;text-align:center;}` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I think I'll stick to my method... :)

Comment: That really depends on your html structure. Anyway, `margin: 0 auto` is the way to go. The this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMcXc/1/), based on @Shmiddty's, but applying auto-margins to all div elements.

Comment: My method worked perfect for both X and Y. Thanks guys.